# Remove Sub Strings pandas, python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a df of high schools.  I'm trying to strip out the generic endings of the school's name.

```
in[1]:df
out[2]:
     time    school
1    09:00   Brown Academy
2    10:00   Covfefe High School
3    11:00   Bradley High
4    12:00   Johnson Prep

school_endings = ['Academy','Prep,'High','High School']
```

Desired:

```
out[3]:
     time    school
1    09:00   Brown
2    10:00   Covfefe
3    11:00   Bradley
4    12:00   Johnson
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
endings = ['Academy', 'Prep', 'High', 'High School']

endings = sorted(endings, key=len, reverse=True)

df.assign(school=df.school.replace(endings, '', regex=True).str.strip())

    time   school
1  09:00    Brown
2  10:00  Covfefe
3  11:00  Bradley
4  12:00  Johnson
```

Answer (score 4):

Using split

```
df.school = df.school.str.split(' ').str[0]

    school  time
0   Brown   09:00
1   Covfefe 10:00
2   Bradley 11:00
3   Johnson 12:00
```

Answer (score 0):

use `rstrip()`method to strip the undesired string from the rear of your original string.
e.g.:

`mystring = "Brown Academy"`

`mystring.rstrip("Academy")` --> will give u the o/p: 'Brown '

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with a regular expression substitution:

```
import re

df['school']=df['school'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+((Academy)|(Prep)|(High)|(High School))$','',x))
```